# Trouble using position in wolfram-mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi im coding a homework in mathematica about finding the probability of a program failing, make a plot and a table with the results however Im having trouble getting the last value of the table

```
Clear[bin1]
bin1[n_, p_, k_] := 
 Module[{prob = (1 - p)^n, i}, 
  Do[prob = (((n - i + 1)/i) (p/(1 - p))) prob, {i, k}]; prob]



distribution = 
  Table[bin1[50, #, k], {k, 0, 50}] & /@ Range[0, .9, .1];
```

thats the probability calculator
`prob = Max[Take[distribution, {#}]] & /@ Range[1, 10]` thats to take the first value of the table (its the porcentage of failiure)

```
position = # & /@ Range[0, .9, .1](thats just for the third value)

max = Last[
  Last[Position[distribution, Take[prob {#}] & /@ Range[1, 10]]]]
```

thats the third value and where i have trouble its supossed to be tha maximum value but the prob{#} part doesnt work i have no idea why

The final table should be: `TableForm[{position, prob, max}]`

Comment: you appear to missing a comma  in the second `Take`.  That said you dont need to use take at all. `Max[Take[distribution, {#}]] & /@ Range[1, 10]` can be simply written as `Max /@ distribution`

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for `Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html):

> `Module[{x,y,…},expr]`
>
> > specifies that occurrences of the symbols x, y, … in expr should be treated as local.

When you say `bin1[n_, p_, k_] := Module[{prob = …}]`, then `prob` is only defined inside the `Module`, and has no value outside.

You can see how this works by playing with it:

```
In[1]:= Module[{foo}, foo]                                                      

Out[1]= foo$185
```

`Module` renames variables inside its scope to have unique names not accessible outside.

You’ll probably need another function to compute `prob`, or set up `bin1[]` to compute both distribution and probability.